# Mutual recursion in primcofix

Tags: isabelle, coinduction

When I write

```
codatatype inftree = node nat inftree inftree

primcorec one :: inftree and two :: inftree where
    "one = node 1 one two"
  | "two = node 2 one two"
```

I get

> "inftree" is neither mutually corecursive with "inftree" nor nested corecursive through itself

Why, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: My guess would be that `primcorec` only supports mutually corecursive functions for mutually corecursive datatypes, i.e. the mutual corecursion of the functions defined must precisely follow the mutual recursion of the codatatype. I don't know how to do what you are trying to do, but then again, I'm hardly an expert – one of the usual suspects w.r.t. codatatypes will probably know, but I would recommend trying the isabelle-users mailing list instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: I was following a talk about coinduction in Coq and trying to make the point that with Isabelle, things are easy enough that I can implement it in Isabelle as the Coq talk went on … but at the point above I failed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Coq has codatatypes and coinduction as primitives in its logic, whereas Isabelle has to construct all of these things on top of HOL. That, of course, makes things a lot more difficult. One solution I can think of would be to introduce an artificially mutually recursive codatatype `inftree1 = node nat inftree1 inftree2` etc., define the `one` and `two` functions on it with `primcorec`, and then transfer the resulting functions to `inftree` using the obvious isomorphisms between the three types.

Comment: Or define one function `f :: nat -> inftree` with `f n = node n (f 1) (f 2)` and define `one = f 1` and `two = f 2`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `primcorec` supports only primitive corecursion, so mutual corecursion is only supported for mutually corecursive codatatypes. Your two functions `one` and `two` are not primitively corecursive and therefore not directly supported. If the more general command `corec` supported mutual corecursion, it would fall into its fragment, but mutual corecursion has not yet been implemented for `corec`. Therefore, you have to find a non-mutual corecursive definition and then define `one` and `two` as derived functions. The canonical solution would be to use a `bool` as an argument:

```
 primcorec one_two :: "bool => inftree" where
    "one_two is_one = Node (if is_one then 1 else 2) (one_two True) (one_two False)"

 definition "one = one_two True"
 definition "two = one_two False"
```

Also, you will have to generalise most properties about `one` and `two`  to `one_two` first before you can prove them by coinduction.